# Check-in problems in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc

I am using Visual Studio Team Services(VSTS) for my project, where the code is handled and used by 50+ team members. 
Recently team members are complaining that it is taking a lot of time for them to check-in the code from Visual Studio Code (they are developing some UI based code in Angular JS) to VSTS, which obviously they don't want.

Why is this happening and what can be the solution for this?

Comment: What's the result if you checkin changes through TF command (check tf.exe path in tfvc.location)?

Comment: The code gets checked in the TF, but to check in a single file it takes 3-4 minutes, which my team mates obviously don't want. They want a faster and seamless check-in through VS Code.

Comment: So, you can reproduce this issue with TF.exe? What's the result if you connect to VSTS through Internet browser, then update a file and check in?

Comment: The file gets updated in the browser the either way, both from the IDE as well as from the VSTS portal. My concern is only the time Visual Studio Code is taking to check in the code to VSTS.

Comment: Which TF.exe you used? In VS installation path (e.g. C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe) or TEE CLC? Try both of them and check the result.